# What was General Franco's disposition towards Islam?

Tags: spain, spanish-civil-war

What was General Franco's disposition towards Islam? He did fight against some rebels in Morocco in the 19-teens, gaining valuable military experience. During the Spanish Civil War, many of the foreign volunteers on the nationalist side were actually Moroccan, so I imagine he was on pretty good terms with Muslims despite being a conservative Catholic.

Can anyone elaborate more about his sentiments about Islam as well as relationships with Muslims, mostly Moroccans?

Comment: Does being Moroccan require a person to be more than a nominal Muslim?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: "Since Franco had relied on thousands of North African soldiers, anti-Islamic sentiment "was played down but the centuries-old myth of the Moorish threat lay at the base of the construction of the "communist menace" as a modern-day Eastern plague".[Wikipedia quoting Michael Richards, ''Unearthing Franco's Legacy'', p. 129.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francoist_Spain#cite_note-51) "  See also [Christian Science Monitor](https://www.csmonitor.com/2002/1002/p07s01-woeu.html#:~:text=Islam%20has%20historically%20been%20a,recognized%20Islam%20only%20in%201989.)

Comment: Many (most) of the Moroccans soldiers were professional soldiers of the Spanish Army **before** the Spanish Civil War began, and AFAIK even those who would have joined later did it mainly for the salary, so I would not call them "volunteers".